# Get image from external URL

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins

I want to grab url from other sites. I don't want to copy them in local gallery but I only need to grab image src from other sites.

For each post I saved the site URL from where I need to get image.
For example custom post type `source_url = http://site-from-where-i-need-to-get-image/pageId123`  In this site I know in which class image is placed. I want to get this image from this site and want to show in my post. is it possible. Is there any plugin ?

What I do to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom field named 'img_url' to your post and then retrieve it in an img tag in your post single template by adding the following :

```
<img src"<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'img_url', true); ?>" />
```